# Merge 'animate' and 'animation' tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

On SO, the [animation](/questions/tagged/animation) tag has [7806 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation) and the [animate](/questions/tagged/animate) tag has [1476 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animate).  I see no distinction between the two tags.  [animation](/questions/tagged/animation) has significantly more questions, and has an appropriate tag wiki.  [animate](/questions/tagged/animate) doesn't have a wiki at all, and is less frequently used.  I suggest [animate](/questions/tagged/animate) is merged into [animation](/questions/tagged/animation), and that [animation](/questions/tagged/animation) be used from now on.

Thoughts, meta? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this calls for a manual clean-up of the [animate](/questions/tagged/animate) tag rather than a merge.  That tag is used an awful lot in conjunction with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), which leads me to think that most uses refer to the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.  Any non-jquery uses of [animate](/questions/tagged/animate) should be retagged to [animation](/questions/tagged/animation), but I don't think we can do this with the moderator tools.

Comment: It cannot be done with the moderator tools. While the "Old Tag Name" field in the "Merge Tags" page seems to accept two tags, it is really accepting a single tag. If you enter _test-2 test-3_, it thinks you meant _test-2test-3_. The autocomplete works for the tags separately, though.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Perhaps that definition should be added to the [tag:animate] tag's tag wiki, so that more questions aren't mislabeled in the future?  And yes, it sounds like we should all try and clean it up together.  Team effort? ;)  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Perhaps there should be a `jquery-animate` tag instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that's a good idea.  Once we clean up all the non-jquery uses of `animate` I can use the tag merge tools to change all the remaining instances to `jquery-animate` in one go.

Comment: @BilltheLizard So THAT took forever! Manual cleanup complete :) I removed the animate tag from all non-jquery questions (except for a migrated question I couldn't edit). I also created the [tag:jquery-animate] tag and wrote the tag wiki for it. So it should be all ready for you to do the special moderator swap of the [tag:animate] tag questions to [tag:jquery-animate]! I'm excited to see it nice and clean, because that took a while to retag all those questions, haha.  Thanks! : D

Comment: @WendiKidd Awesome!  Thanks a lot for doing that.  Now I noticed that there's already a synonym from `jquery-animate` to `jquery-animation`.  It already had 700+ uses, so I wonder if we should keep that and just move the tag wiki to it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Hmm...  Since the function itself is called `animate()`, personally I'd think it best to merge the `jquery-animation` questions into `jquery-animate`.  But that's your call ;)

Comment: @WendiKidd Yeah, I agree.  Thanks again.

Comment: Isn't it a bit broad to have animate as a synonym of jquery-animate? Wouldn't it be more logical just to allow community moderation to edit out any question which uses animate to mean jquery-animate?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Is there some other use for an animate tag?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm not sure, however `animate` is a word which doesn't have its roots in jQuery. What if you wanted to animate an image within a C++ application, for instance?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Then you'd use the animation tag. The tagging UI guides you toward that tag already. http://i.stack.imgur.com/etDi1.png